# Distribution of bivariate vectors for strictly stationary processes

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, time-series, stationary-processes

Consider a strictly stationary process $X_t$, $t\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. Could you help me to disprove the following statement:

"For $t, s > 0$, the bivariate vectors $(X_s, X_t)$ and $(X_t, X_s)$ have the same distribution."

I think the statement is false in general but true for Gaussian processes. Can we find a counter-example which proves that the statement is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_t=\sum_{j\geqslant 0}2^{-j}\varepsilon_{t-j}$, where $\left(\varepsilon_{j}\right)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli random variables with parameters $1/2$. Then $X_1=X_0/2+\varepsilon_1$. If $(X_0,X_1)$ has the same distribution as $(X_1,X_0)$, then $X_1-X_0/2$ would have the same distribution as $X_0-X_1/2$, that is, $X_0-X_1/2$ would have the same distribution as $\varepsilon_1$ which
cannot be the case, since the former is the sum of two independent random variables, one having a Bernoulli distribution, the other a uniform distribution.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer!